# How do I tell the spider to stop requesting after n failed requests?

Tags: scrapy

```
import scrapy

class MySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    start_urls = []
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        for i in range(1, 1000):
            self.start_urls.append("some url"+i)

    def parse(self, response):
        print(response)
```

Here we queue 1000 urls in `__init__` function, but I want to stop making all those requests if it fails or returns something undesirable. How do I tell the spider to stop making requests say after 10 failed requests.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to set [`CLOSESPIDER_ERRORCOUNT`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html#closespider-errorcount) to 10 in that case. It probably doesn't account for failed requests only, though. Alternatively, you might set [`HTTPERROR_ALLOWED_CODES`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html#httperror-allowed-codes) to handle even the error responses (failed requests) and implement your own failed request counter inside the spider. Then, when the counter is above threshold, you raise [`CloseSpider`](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#scrapy.exceptions.CloseSpider) exception yourself.